# why the result isn't what I expected in Nodejs promise?

Tags: node.js, promise

I wrote test code for bluebird in Node.js like this:

```
var Promise = require(‘bluebird’)
var obj = {
      func1: function () {
               return ‘foo’
      },
      func2: function () {
              return ‘bar’
      }
}
console.log("==================================")
Promise.promisifyAll(obj)

obj.func1Async().then(function (result) {
      console.log(result)
})
```

what i expected is to print the "foo", but actually nothing output. 
is there something wrong?

Comment: Ovidiu's answer will solve your issue :-) Also, you can just do: `obj.func1Async().then(console.log)` and avoid some boilerplate code.

Comment: I don't understand, what i think is 
` obj.func1Async()  ` returns a promise, and can call then method, pass the return value "foo" to then. like fs:  ` fs.readFileAsync('filename').then(function(content) { console.log(content) })` 
 what's the difference?

Answer (score 3):

After looking around for a while, it seems that Bluebird promisify works on node-style functions, which are as follows:

- may accept 0..N parameters first
- last parameter is always a callback
- callback needs to be called with (error, data) params in that order.

So in your case, code should be:

```
var obj = {
  func1: function (cb) { // note if you add params they need to be before cb and always passed when invoking the func1Async version
    cb(null, 'foo'); // null => no error
  },
  func2: function (cb) {
    cb(null, 'bar'); // null => no error
  }
}
```

Then it works. Ugly - but it's how it should be.

Comment: I don't understand, what i think is obj.func1Async() returns a promise, and can call then method, pass the return value "foo" to then.
like fs:
fs.readFileAsync('filename').then(function(content) {
   console.log(content)
})
what's the difference?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean.. .but with the `obj` defined as in my answer is conform to what bluebird expects to be able to give you the promise you expect (if you look at fs.readFile function implementation you will see it has a similar signature with the conditions i mentioned). So if you want to use bluebird to obtain the same result, you must conform your function implementation to those conditions as well. If you just want a promise from a function you can just do it yourself `var func1Async = () => new Promise(res => res(func1()))`